# unhiding specific field in jquery when validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Edit:

I'm using jquery validate plugin. All the error messages are actually displayed in the background, but I hid them originally. When I check that input field, then I want to unhide the error message if it's invalid. I don't want all the error messages to popup in the other fields already. I'm using $('#form').valid() constantly. Why I am doing this is I need to somehow synchronize with the buttons I have. I need to have the jquery validate plugin to constantly check if the $('#form').valid() so I can match up with the ON and OFF IMG buttons I have. The IMG ON and OFF either show() or hide() accordingly.

Right now I have all .error `<div>` hidden. Is there a way to only unhide only that `<div class="error">`. Let say I'm checking for 2nd input #error2. If there is an error, I want to only unhide `<div class="error"><div id="error2"> </div></div>` using this keyword? I only want to unhide this section.

```
$('.error this').show();
```

For example:

```
<div id="#form">
    <input type="text" data-error="#error1"/>
    <div class="error">
       <div id="error1"> </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" data-error="#error2"/>
    <div class="error">
       <div id="error2"> </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" data-error="#error3"/>
    <div class="error">
       <div id="error3"> </div>
    </div>

    <img id="on">ON BUTTON</img>
    <img id="off">OFF BUTTON</img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery code:

```
$(this).parent().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes

```
if ($('div').hasClass('.error'))
 {
     $(this).show();
     $(this).find('div').show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("[data-error],.error").hide();
$("#error2").parent().show().prev().show();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lohervar/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('#error2').parent().show();
```